# Python: Compare last elements in a list

Tags: python, pandas, list

I am working with a column containing lists of strings, and would like to compare the last element in each row. If the final elements do not match, I want to create a new variable that would have the first and last elements concatenated like this:
 `element[0].element[-1]`

If they do match, I'd like to differentiate between them by appending the next element in the list:
`element[0].element[-2].element[-1]`

I have made this column a list from its original format. Here is a snippet of the original variable from the `pandas` dataframe:

```
apple.banana.pear
apple.starfruit.grape
apple.kiwi.orange.pear
apple.durian.coconut
Name: original, Length: 4, dtype: string

mylist = df['original'].apply(lambda x: x.split('.'))
```

My current list:

```
[apple, banana, pear]
[apple, starfruit, grape]
[apple, kiwi, orange, pear]
[apple, durian, coconut]
```

Desired output:

```
apple.banana.pear
apple.grape
apple.orange.pear
apple.coconut
```

I'm not sure if making it into a list is optimal, but figured it would be easier to access each portion as an element. That may not be the case. Here is what I've tried:

```
l = 0
j = l + 1
for l in mylist:
    for j in mylist:
        if mylist[l][-1] == mylist[j][-1]:
            newvar = mylist[l][0] + '.' + mylist[l][-2] + '.' + mylist[l][-1]
        else:
            newvar = mylist[l][0] + '.' + mylist[l][-1]

KeyError: "None of [Index(['apple', 'banana', 'pear'], dtype='object')] are in the [index]"
```

Any suggestions are greatly appreciated.

Comment: how you define match here ?

Comment: If the last element in the row is the same as another. Since rows 0 and 2 have `pear` as their last element, it would append their previous element to the new variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can do

```
s=df.original.str.split('.')
df['new']=np.where(s.str[-1].duplicated(keep=False),
                   s.str[0]+'.'+s.str[-2]+'.'+s.str[-1],
                   s.str[0]+'.'+s.str[-1])
df
Out[47]: 
                 original                new
0       apple.banana.pear  apple.banana.pear
1   apple.starfruit.grape        apple.grape
2  apple.kiwi.orange.pear  apple.orange.pear
3    apple.durian.coconut      apple.coconut
```

Comment: Amazing! Would there be a way to include if both variables belonged to the next element as well? Say there is `apple.banana.orange.pear` for the first entry. Could I then run it again to specify the indices as `np.where(s.str[-2:-1]...` to differentiate? Thanks for your help.

Comment: @Justin724 np.where(s.str[-3:-1].apply(tuple).duplicated().....)